# Standalone Apache Camel application doesn' run

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm on this problem: can't get my apache camel batch run. Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class Launch {

private Main main;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Launch l = new Launch();
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("from") +" -> "+System.getProperty("to"));
    try {
        l.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void execute() throws Exception {
    main = new Main();
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new FromFileToFile());
    main.run();
}

private static class FromFileToFile extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        onException(Exception.class).handled(true).process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                arg0.getException().printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        from(System.getProperty("from") + "")
                .filter(body().contains("DOTHIS"))
                .process(new Processor() {

                    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(arg0.getIn().getBody()
                                .toString());
                    }
                }).to(System.getProperty("to"))
                .to(System.getProperty("to") + ".BAK");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to use the `Thread.sleep(...)` workaround. I simply copied and modified the source stuff posted on [this](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html) official docs page. When I run my dummy program using Eclipse, application simply hangs. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What are your System.getProperty("from") and System.getProperty("to")?

Comment: Just a couple of path: `file://Users/francesco/Desktop/ace/filefrom.txt` and `file://Users/francesco/Desktop/ace/good.xml`. I'm using windows.

Comment: Camel supports only consuming from directory path, see further [here](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html). It is now trying to consume files from directory named "filefrom.txt" but that of course does not exists since that's your file. Do you get same problem if you change your from URI to "file://Users/francesco/Desktop/ace?fileName=filefrom.txt" ?

Comment: My bad! The `fileName`. Ok I corrected my code but application still hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem about path. I passed arguments as options like this:
`file://Users/francesco/..`
As I'm using windows I must specify uri like this 
`file:///C:/Users/francesco/..`
The batch doesn't hangs, it continues to poll directory for new files to consumes.

Answer (score 1):

Your application doesn't probably hang, it just won't do anything. :)

You have defined filter that checks if Camel Message body contains word "DOTHIS". When you consume file with File consumer the body will be of type GenericFile. Then when your filter checks for that string it surely won't find it since the body is not string.

**Solution**: Convert file body to string first and then your filter will work and you get the result you were expecting. Conversion can be done like this

```
from(System.getProperty("from") + "")        
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
    .filter(body().contains("DOTHIS"))
```

You might also want to increase logging level so you can get the grasp of what's going on in your route.

Comment: It's not the answer but you were on the right way when you comment about path. I'm using windows and (shame) the correct path is not file://Users/... but file:///C:/Users/.... Now the batch produce the two files. The batch doesn't hangs, it continues to poll the directory.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hangs'? Can you post the log to your question and explain what you would expect to happen instead of what is currently happening?

Comment: It doesn't hangs, I was wrong. The batch continues to poll the directory looking for new files.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread your first comment somehow. So is your application now working?

Comment: Yes It works. Thankyou, weekend support worth double to me.